# Properties.containsKey returns false, why?

Tags: java, hashtable

```
Properties segmentClients = new Properties();
segmentClients.load(new FileInputStream(pathSegmentFile));

segmentClients.containsKey(strANI); //returns false / strANI = "9202599784"
```

file is like this:

```
# 01.2012
9202599784
9202599573
9208552001
9209374107
9209374949
```

strANI = 9202599784

why does it return false?

**UPD**: The problem was that file was in Unicode, after saving in ANSI started to work

Comment: That's not a properties file...

Comment: A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would really help...

Comment: @skaffman I kind of agree, although technically all those numbers are just keys to empty strings. Not a useful properties file but...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`segmentClients.containsKey("9202599784");` will return true because:

> Each key and its corresponding value in the property list is a string.

proof, this test will pass:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(new StringBufferInputStream("# 01.2012\n" +
                "9202599784\n" +
                "9202599573\n"));
assertTrue(p.containsKey("9202599784"));
```

Comment: strANI is a String which = "9202599784"

Comment: Thank you for your help, the problem was that file was in Unicode, after saving in ANSI - now works!

Comment: that was going to be my next guess (since you're not getting a fileNotFound exp) :)

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the properties file is found and opened.